# Lost in trying to create user database system

Tags: php, database, login, sql, cms

I've done a lot of reading and am still lost in how to approach my website. My goal is to have a login system, where these users have their own content they can save and manipulate. Say for example a game of sorts where users pick certain elements and cross-compare them to gain points etc.

It seems like there are many ways of achieving this and all the guides are not specific enough to my purpose so I was hoping to get pointed in the right direction. Currently my website just uses a basic theme and elementor to edit static pages, and I'm hoping to keep this intact to deal with aesthetics (I don't want to do all the html/css by hand, thats why I picked wordpress).

Options I have considered:

-Using login plugins that already exist -> how to connect this user login data with their content, will these plugins create tables in sql I can access?

-Using php sessions to create login system from scratch -> willing to code this, but not sure how to integrate this into wordpress, I can make custom pages and see them in my pages tab, but can't edit with elemantor or anything, and I'm trying to avoid doing all my own html/css. Can I use shortcodes to put all my php within pages or is that getting ugly, and can session variables work between separate shortcodes?

-Create my own plugin for the content system -> again how do I integrate this into my wordpress pages and with my login system, or can I do this all in one plugin? Can I just plop this in on any page and have it work?

Basically, I'm overwhelmed and have no idea where to go, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Also, I am using a LAMP system if that matters.

Comment: I believe that you need to know php and WordPress API in order to do this. A step forward, if know php programming is to [create your own plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). About the login and sessions, WordPress already does that.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to look into WP Multisite. This allows each user to have their own site, so they're sandboxed and can't affect other users' content. WP already handles logins all on its own, so don't worry about sessions and don't try to code your own login system outside of it if you do use WP. Depending on the type of game you'll probably end up needing to code some PHP yourself - WP has great building blocks and plugins, but not always something out of the box for every use.

Comment: @WebElaine did some research into multisites, not sure its what I'm looking for. I'm leaning towards a fantasy kind of game with sports so users make their picks and can enter leagues etc. How would it work if there are many users? How would they each have their own sub-domain?

Comment: So from both of the respones I gather I should definitely stick to wordpress' login system. My question is if I can link this user registration data with other content on my website.

Comment: Yes, you can check whether the user is logged in, and what permission level the user has, and code off of that in both themes and plugins. If users need to interact then no, MultiSite is probably not what you need, but I'm not sure WP is really the best route either. Whatever you do, it's going to require significant custom code.

Comment: Ya it definitely will require custom code, and I'm hoping I can create that functionality in some sort of modular form, while keeping the useful features of wordpress in terms of aesthetics and stuff. Would it be viable to do all of that in a plugin, then throw it on my website or no?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can start from custom post types--> custom metas? 
then create custom roles. 
You will be able to limit the access by roles.